# Sharing message queues among threads (in Windows)

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Is there any way to share a message queue among several threads, or otherwise to read a message queue of a different thread, without using hooks?

Comment: You're talking of window messages, right? Because the term "message queue" is often used for MSMQ.

Comment: Yes... but it's almost always a bad idea. Why don't you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783073/processing-messages-is-too-slow-resulting-in-a-jerky-unresponsive-ui-how-can

Answer (score 1):

GetMessage and PeekMessage only read messages for the current thread, you can't use them to read messages sent to the input queue owned by  another thread.

Try joining the thread input queues using [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956(VS.85).aspx), that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Messages in a message queue can be differentiated on the basis of the window they're for, but I don't think messages can be differentiated on the basis of an inteded thread - the fields just aren't there in the MSG structure - so I don't think you can share a queue over multiple threads.

That leaves you with a non-hook monitoring solution.

I'm pretty sure you could peek another threads queue, but the problem is you're basically polling; so you'll miss messages.

Do you have any influence over the threads you wish to read?  if so, you can get them to rebroadcast their messages to you.

Apart from that, I can't see a way to do this.

Comment: Theoretically yes, and I see where you're going with this, but it's not the solution i'm looking for.