# PeekMessage Thread Safety

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a thread that captures the state of all input devices every x milliseconds.  To do this, I am using `GetAsyncKeyState()` for all keys, `GetCursorPos()` for mouse x/y, and `XInputGetState()` for controller state.  What this doesn't report is the mouse's scroll wheel, which isn't expressed in a single value but a change in value, which means it must be determined through a window message (`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`).

Is it safe to call `PeekMessage()` from this thread (which is not my message pump thread), provided I use my own synchronization?

Comment: It might be safe in terms of only one thread calling the function at a time, but might not give the result you expect, or even work at all. Only the tread creating the window should handle the messages. See e.g. [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964117/440558).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I guess the solution is to use the mousewheel for gui only, and handle any gui state on the message pump / rendering thread.  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: Each thread has its own message queue, and `PeekMessage` only looks in the queue of the calling thread. So yes, it's thread-safe, but it won't do you any good as `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` is likely not sent to your worker thread, and won't be found in its message queue. `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` goes to the thread that created the window currently having focus.

Comment: Side note: If you are using [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) be sure to read the remarks section in the docs. Basically, the pressed since previous call flag is a global state provided only for compatibility and if another application (or another instance of your program) calls it you might miss some key presses.